Quarkus and Keycloak compatibility
I need to use the latest Quarkus release version (3.11), but I have to interact with an old Keycloak version (15.0.2).
If I use the latest keycloak-admin-client version I have compatibility problems when I try to create users or grups etc.. (for example: Unrecognized field "userProfileMetadata" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation)).
So I tried to use the version 15.0.2 of keycloak-admin-client and, in this case, I had problems with jakarta and javax packages compatibility. I so tried to import javax.ws.rs-api dependency but, even if I hadn't errors in Eclipse, project didn't compile
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.11.0:build (default) on project nabook-server: Failed to build quarkus application: Failed to load steps from class io.quarkus.keycloak.admin.client.reactive.KeycloakAdminClientReactiveProcessor: org/keycloak/admin/client/spi/ResteasyClientProvider: org.keycloak.admin.client.spi.ResteasyClientProvider -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :nabook-server

My question is: is there a way to use latest versions of Quarkus with oldest Keycloak versions?

Had the same issue with creation of new users. If there is no option for Keycloak upgrade, I suggest extending the UserRepresentation like this:
public class CustomUserRepresentation extends UserRepresentation {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public void setUserProfileMetadata(UserProfileMetadata userProfileMetadata) {
        super.setUserProfileMetadata(userProfileMetadata);
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public UserProfileMetadata getUserProfileMetadata() {
        return super.getUserProfileMetadata();
    }
}

It worked in our environment.
